# Что делает фрагментный шейдер в OpenGL4?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, шейдеры

Правильно ли я понял.. фрагментный шейдер занимается цветом пикселей? Допустим квадрат 1000 на 1000 пикселей.. что бы его покрасить нужен один шейдер. И он держит под контролем все эти пиксели 1000ми ядер?

Comment: Очень грубо говоря - да. GPU раздает ядрам указание "покрасить такой-то пиксель текущим шейдером".